# Faster way of developing and Testing new Nifi Processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I am developing new Nifi processor for my data flow. I make code changes in eclipse , creates new .nar file and copy it to Nifi lib for testing it.

On ever nar update Nifi needs a restart which takes a significant amount of time.

Is there any better way of testing your new .nar in Nifi ? Because restarting Nifi for every small change reduces your development speed.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few options for rapid prototyping and testing that make developing Apache NiFi processors easier.

1. Model your code in [`ExecuteScript`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html) -- using the `ExecuteScript` processor means you can make code changes to the domain-related code (whatever you type into the processor `Script Body` property or a file referenced by `Script File`) without having to build anything or restart the application. You can replay the same flowfiles through the updated code using the [provenance replay feature](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#replaying-a-flowfile). You can also test your scripts directly with Matt Burgess' [NiFi Script Tester](https://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/06/testing-executescript-processor-scripts.html) tool. Once you have acceptable behavior, take the script body and migrate it to a custom processor that can be deployed.
2. Use the [unit testing and integration testing](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#testing) features of NiFi -- the test harnesses and "runners" provided by the core framework will allow you to simulate flow scenarios in automated tests before deploying the entire application. It takes a little time to build out the first flow, but once you do, it's a repeatable and understandable process which you can use to cover edge cases and ensure desired behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Just check how testing done for standard nifi processors. And do the same. For example look at dbcp https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-services/nifi-dbcp-service-bundle/nifi-dbcp-service/src

For those tests you don't need to start nifi.